# Plugin WP para mostrar hora da publicação dos posts

Tags: wordpress, post, plugin, plugin-wordpress, atualização

Ola, tenho um site Wordpress e gostaria de mostrar o horário de publicação dos posts.

meu site é o www.urgentenews.com.br

Alguém conhece algum plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No menu administrativo: **Opções -> Geral**, vá no campo **Formato da data** e selecione a opção **Personalizado**.

Lá você poderá criar um formato de saída específico.

Se você colocar o formato `j \d\e F  \d\e  Y,  H:i\h` os posts devem aparecer mais ou menos como `25 de Maio de 2018, 01:12h`.

Comment: Valeu amigo pela dica preciosa, muito obrigado, Deus abençoe